# from long data table to wide data table

Tags: r, if-statement, data-manipulation, tidyr

_aI am trying to transform the dataset. What i want to achieve is that if `Intensitat` = 1 - R creates a new column - Intensity 1a - and writes the value of `damage_a`. If `Intensitat` = 2 - R creates another new column - Intensity 2a - and writes the values of `damage_a`. Finally if Intensitat = 3 then R does new column - Intensity 3a - and writes the values of `damage_a`. (it always writes the value of damage_x corresponding to the same row as the intensity indicator).

Then I will run the same process: create 3 columns from an indicator variables - each column for an indicator value and in each column use the values of `damage_b`.

Lastly the same again but use the values of `damage_c`.

```
type <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 5, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
type

intensity <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 3, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
intensity

damage_a <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 50, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
damage_b <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 200, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
damage_c <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 500, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)

dat <- data.frame(type, intensity, damage_a, damage_b, damage_c)

# want to  evaluate if the difference in mean  between different damages 
  dat1 <- subset(dat, select = c(type, intensity, damage_a))
  dat2 <- subset(dat, select = c(type, intensity, damage_b))
  dat3 <- subset(dat, select = c(type, intensity, damage_c))
```

It might seem like an very easy task for you, but I have been stuck on this for two days. I have tried applyin tidyr function, ifelse comands, etc but never obtained what i needed. Any comments/ideas are very appriciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**:

I managed to change the format if the table with this little handy function.

```
df.out <- unstack(dat, damage_a ~ intensity)
```

The problem now is that i get lists that differ in lenght. How can i combine these lists into ona data frame?

Comment: Perhaps `library(data.table);dcast(setDT(dat), type + rowid(type, intensity) ~ paste0("intensity_", intensity), value.var = c('damage_a', 'damage_b', 'damage_c'))`

Comment: yes something like that, but why is there a `type_f` variable in your code? could you explain a little what the comands do?

Comment: I posted the comment as a solution with some explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns.  As there are multiple observations per group, we can use the `rowid` function to create a sequence variable by 'type' and 'intensity' in the formula.  This will result in a new column 'type_1', but it can be assigned to `NULL` later

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dat), type + rowid(type, intensity) ~ paste0("intensity_", 
  intensity), value.var = c('damage_a', 'damage_b', 'damage_c'))[, type_1 := NULL][]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the gather and spread functions in tidyr, e.g.

```
dat <- tidyr::spread(dat, damage, value, -intensity, -type)   
tidyr::spread(dat, damage, value)
```